# How to find all single free positions when comparing one array to another?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have created two arrays of type CGPoint (`allPos` and `selectedPos`). One contains the other. Please see an example of them below:

```
allPos = [point1,..., point10]
selectedPos = [point1, point4, point6, point7, point9, point10]
```

All points have the same `y` coordinate and I have arranged them from smallest to largest.

How can I find an array of positions from `allPos` that have only **one free consecutive position or only one in-between free position** when compared to `selectedPos`?
From my example above that would be

```
[point5, point8]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is selectedPos array, just look at the following positions after every point and see if there is (only) one empty spot or (only) 3 and save that into a new array.

Answer (score 0):

I create simle example for you that show how it is possible to find position of the elements that are missing.

```
let first = [1,2,6,8,9,10]
let second = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

func fetchIndexesWithoutConsecutive(firstArray: [Int], secondArray: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    //Output array
    var array = [Int]()

    //Enumerate second array and compare if first array conteins this elments if not we add postion of the missing item
    for (index, value) in secondArray.enumerate() {
        if (!firstArray.contains(value)) {
            array.append(index)
        }
    }

    guard array.count > 1 else {
        return array
    }

    var result = [Int]()

    for i in 0...array.count-2 {
        let first = array[i]
        let second = array[i+1]
        if second - first > 1 {
            result.append(second)
        }
    }

    return result // [6] position of the elements in second array that are not in first array without consecutive
}

fetchIndexesWithoutConsecutive(first, secondArray: second)
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't fully solve my issue. Your code will provide all free positions but I am only interested in the ones that have single free spaces. Using my example of `allPos` and `selectedPos`, the code you provided will result in `[point2, point3, point5, point8]`. I would only need the single free spaces (no consecutive free spaces) which are `[point5, point8]`. I hope this explains things better

Comment: It is hard to understand could you describe points with real data

Comment: Say I have two `Int` arrays `allPos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` and `selectedPos = [1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]` arranged in a given order (ascending). When comparing `allPos` and `selectedPos`, the unselected elements are `[2, 3, 5, 8]`. `2`, `3` are consecutive elements, and I don’t want consecutive elements in my results. But `5` and `8` are not consecutive. So I am interested in `[5, 8]` being my final filtered array since they are the only unselected items that are not consecutive.